# Why footnote doesn't work in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, footnotes

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Hello\footnote{World!} \\
Hello\tablefootnote{World!} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I see footnote marks, but I don't see footnote texts. What is wrong?

Comment: as should be documented in any manual that tells you `\footnote` command exists, it has to be in the top level of the page so it can migrate to the end, a simple `\mbox` would be enough to stop it, it doesn't have to be in a tabular. You can use `\footnotemark` in the tabular and `\footnotetext` somewher safe where the text can migrate.

Answer (score 1):

I will make the assumption that in your real documents, the footnotes associated with tabular material are a bit less simplistic than "World". If that's indeed the case, you may want to familiarize yourself with the powerful `threeparttable` package, its `\tnote` macro, and its `tablenotes` environment. The argument of `\tnote` can be just about any symbol, and arguments can be repeated if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open look
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
Hello\tnote{a} \\
Goodbye\tnote{*} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] World!
\item[*] World.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yay, yet another table package and environment.

Answer (score 1):

When using [tablefootnote](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote), in the first line of your tabular it should be `\tablefootnote` instead of `\footnote`. Then the two `\tablefootnote` commands are in a `tabular`, but not in a `table` environment. Either add a `table` environment:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Hello\footnote{World!} \\
Hello\tablefootnote{World!} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

(and maybe `\centering`, `\caption[...]{...}`, `\label{...}`, ...),

or a `\spewnotes` after the tabular, so that the tablefootnote package knows that you finished the table:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
Hello\footnote{World!} \\
Hello\tablefootnote{World!} \\
\end{tabular}
\spewnotes
```

The command `\spewnotes` is not yet defined in current version 2014/01/27 1.1c of package tablefootnote, thus after

```
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
```

it is necessary to write:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tablefootnote}{2014/01/27}
  {\relax% should include \spewnotes
  }%
  {\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
      \ltx@ifpackageloaded{footnotebackref}{%
        \LetLtxMacro{\tfncurrentmft}{\@makefntext}%
        \LetLtxMacro{\@makefntext}{\tablemakefntext}%
         \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
        \LetLtxMacro{\@makefntext}{\tfncurrentmft}%
       }{% footnotebackref not loaded
        \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
       }%
      \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
      \global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax% just to be sure and safe
    }%
  }
\makeatother
```

Thus the complete document reads:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tablefootnote}{2014/01/27}
  {% should include \spewnotes
  }%
  {\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
      \ltx@ifpackageloaded{footnotebackref}{%
        \LetLtxMacro{\tfncurrentmft}{\@makefntext}%
        \LetLtxMacro{\@makefntext}{\tablemakefntext}%
         \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
        \LetLtxMacro{\@makefntext}{\tfncurrentmft}%
       }{% footnotebackref not loaded
        \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
       }%
      \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
      \global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax% just to be sure and safe
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Hello\tablefootnote{World!} \\
Hello\tablefootnote{World!} \\
\end{tabular}
\spewnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: an up to date LaTeX has `\DeclareCommandCopy` and `\NewCommandCopy` which can be used instead of `\LetLtxMacro` :)